# C: Overwrite Array2D values not working when using function

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want `max` to have the content of `tmp_max`. `max` is dynamically allocated. `tmp_max` size is known.

Copying the values is working correctly when I hardcode it but it doesn't work when I create a function to copy the values. Why is that?

```
//This code works
int** max;
init2D(&max,3,4);

int tmp_max[3][4] = {{3,3,2,2}, {1,2,3,4}, {1,3,5,0}};

for(int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++)
    for(int j = 0 ; j < 4; j++)
        max[i][j] = tmp_max[i][j];

assert(max[0][1] == 3);
```

---

```
//This one crashes
void copyArray2D(int a, int b, int*** tab,int*** tab2){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < a; i++)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < b; j++)
            tab2[i][j] = tab[i][j];
}

int** max;
init2D(&max,3,4);

int tmp_max[3][4] = {{3,3,2,2}, {1,2,3,4}, {1,3,5,0}};
copyArray2D(3,4,&tmp_max,&max); //crash

assert(max[0][1] == 3);
```

Note:

Using `void copyArray2D(int a, int b, int** tab,int** tab2){`and `copyArray2D(3,4,max,tmp_max);` isn't working either.

Using `void copyArray2D(int a, int b, int** tab,int** tab2){`and `copyArray2D(3,4,&max,&tmp_max);` isn't working either.

```
void init2D(int ***data_ptr, int x, int y) {
    int **data = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * x);
    for (int k = 0; k < x; k++)
        data[k] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * y);
    *data_ptr = data;
}
```

Comment: You have too many stars in the second function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second function has too many stars.  You hadn't shown the `init2D` function when I first wrote an answer, so I had to guess what you'd done with that (but the code is now in the question and is close enough to what I produced that the difference is immaterial — except I do error check the allocations).  Here's a (rewritten) version of the code (the first version hadn't been near a compiler, and I completely missed a crucial detail).  Note that `int **` is not the same as `int arr[N][M]` or variations on the theme — even if you use the same notation to access both.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void copyArray2D(int a, int b, int **dst, int src[a][b])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            dst[i][j] = src[i][j];
}

static void oom(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
    exit(1);
}

static void init2D(int ***arr, int a, int b)
{
    (*arr) = malloc(a * sizeof((*arr)[0]));
    if (*arr == 0)
        oom();
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        (*arr)[i] = malloc(b * sizeof((*arr)[0][0]));
        if ((*arr)[i] == 0)
            oom();
    }
}

static void dump_2d_array(int a, int b, int arr[a][b])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            printf(" %2d", arr[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

static void dump_2d_pointers(int a, int b, int **arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            printf(" %2d", arr[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int **max;
    init2D(&max, 3, 4);

    int tmp_max[3][4] = { { 3, 3, 2, 2 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 1, 3, 5, 0 } };
    copyArray2D(3, 4, max, tmp_max);
    printf("2D array:\n");
    dump_2d_array(3, 4, tmp_max);
    printf("List of pointers:\n");
    dump_2d_pointers(3, 4, max);
    return 0;
}
```

Output from running that code:

```
2D array:
  3  3  2  2
  1  2  3  4
  1  3  5  0
List of pointers:
  3  3  2  2
  1  2  3  4
  1  3  5  0
```

Note that I've not written a free function, so the memory is leaked.

Be wary of [3-Star Programming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: Why would be a 3 star programmer, if you can be a 5 star programmer?

Comment: The content of `init2D` is in the Note section. It is working now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler should complain about `copyArray2D(3,4,&tmp_max,&max)`.

You must fix any issues identified by your compiler before trying to run your code (running any such executable based on broken code is meaningless).

One problem is that `copyArray2D` says `int***` when it should say `int**`.

After fixing that, the main issue here is that you have written `copyArray2D` so that it only works with an array of pointers.  (You are simulating a 2-D array by allocating an array of pointers, and then making each pointer point to a separate allocation representing each row).

This works when you use `init2D` because the `init2D` function allocates an array of pointers etc.

However `int tmp_max[3][4]` is a block of 12 contiguous ints. There are no pointers. This is not compatible with `copyArray2D`.

Your options are:

- Use `int **tmp_max` and use `init2D` to allocate it, instead of `int tmp_max[3][4]`
- Make another version of `copyArray2D` which works on a contiguous 2-D array.
- Use an ugly macro

Comment: How can I insert values in `int** tmp_max`?  Is `tmp_max[0][0] = 1`, `tmp_max[0][1] = 2` the only way?

Comment: @RainingChain yes (once you allocated space via init2D of course)

Answer (score 0):

```
void copyArray2D(int a, int b, int tab[a][b],int*** tab2){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < a; i++)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < b; j++)
            (*tab2)[i][j] = tab[i][j];
}

copyArray2D(3,4,tmp_max,&max);
```